# How can I set a default map size and zoom level in Battlefield 3? (PC)

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

Is there any way to set a default map size and zoom level so that one does not have to hit M key and N key when respawning or entering / exiting a vehicle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no way to do this. Which is very annoying when it resets to the default size (not zoom) when pretty much anything happens, including a team mate entering or exiting the vehicle you're in.

Comment: I really hope they fix this with the upcoming patch